# SQL Azure - Create complex Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, azure-sql-database, pivot-table

This question is all for SQL Azure. I have a data set for various commodity prices by year and a unit price like:

Rice - 2007 - 0.5
Rice - 2007 - 0.3
Rice - 2007 - 0.8
Wheat - 2006 - 1.1
Wheat - 2006 - 1.4
etc

How can I create a pivot table that gives me the MAX and MIN price paid for each year for each commodity? I know how to do a pivot table that would give me something like the average - thats pretty easy. But I need my "main" pivot column to be the year and then each year would have its 2 "sub columns" for a MIN and MAX price and I'm not quite sure how to do that. Help!

Comment: No worries, @bluefeet will be along in about 60 seconds to give you an answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something in your explanation, you can do this easily without the PIVOT function:

```
select product,
  year,
  min(price) MinPrice,
  max(price) MaxPrice
from yourtable
group by product, year
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfc88/1).

If you want the data in separate columns, then there are a few ways that you can do this.

**Aggregate function with CASE:**

```
select product,
  min(case when year=2006 then price else 0 end) [2006_MinPrice],
  max(case when year=2006 then price else 0 end) [2006_MaxPrice],
  min(case when year=2007 then price else 0 end) [2007_MinPrice],
  max(case when year=2007 then price else 0 end) [2007_MaxPrice]
from yourtable
group by product
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfc88/11)

**UNPIVOT and PIVOT:**

The UNPIVOT is used to transform your column data into rows. Once in the rows, you can create the new columns with the year and then pivot:

```
select *
from
(
  select product, 
    cast(year as varchar(4))+'_'+col as piv_col,
    value
  from
  (
    select product,
      year,
      min(price) MinPrice,
      max(price) MaxPrice
    from yourtable
    group by product, year
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value for col in (minPrice, maxPrice)
  ) u
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for piv_col in ([2006_MinPrice], [2006_MaxPrice],
                  [2007_MinPrice], [2007_MaxPrice])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfc88/13). These give the result:

```
| PRODUCT | 2006_MINPRICE | 2006_MAXPRICE | 2007_MINPRICE | 2007_MAXPRICE |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Rice |             0 |             0 |           0.3 |           0.8 |
|   Wheat |           1.1 |           1.4 |             0 |             0 |
```

If you have an unknown number of years, then you coul also implement dynamic sql.

Comment: Yes, thats the rather obvious answer. But this is a pivot table with the years as columns. So the output columns would be like: Commodity-2006-2007-2008 etc and then the rows would be the min and max for each year. The reply above would give me the results in a tabular format, I need it as a pivot

Comment: Can you edit your OP and show how you want the min/max displayed with the year? That will be easier to understand.

Comment: @JimBeam See my edit, I added a few versions that separate the years into columns.

Comment: Thank you! I think the second example (min max with case) is along the right lines. I guess its not a pivot after all, it should give me what I need. I'll try that. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JimBeam Happy to help, it is still a pivot. It is just what they used to call a poor main's pivot. :)